# Determining an interest rate

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is the flat rate of interest per annum, correct to one decimal
> place, charged on the Mazda 4-door if making term payments?
>
> **Mazda 4-door**
>
> \$15790 cash or \$500 deposit and \$92 per week over 5 years

So the interest paid is 92 * 52 * 5 = \$23,920

Interest = PRICE * RATE * PERIOD

23920 = 1570 * R * 5

23920 = (1570 * 5) * R

$\frac{23920}{1570 * 5}$ = R

R = 30.2%

Which is clearly not the answer as the answer should be 11.3%

Comment: There seems to be a couple of errors.  First, did you factor in the $500$ dollar deposit on the payment plan?  Also, where you wrote $1570$, did you mean $15790$?

Comment: Also, the interest paid should be the total amount paid *minus the \$15790*.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of interest is how much more you have to pay in the long haul compared to how much the car would cost if buying it outright. The amount that is paid over the $5$ years in dollars is $92\times 52\times 5+500=24420$ (you forgot to add in the $500$ deposit).

This is $24420-15790=8630$ more dollars than buying it upfront would have been. Hence the total amount of interest is $\dfrac{8630}{15790}\approx55\%$. However, we are asked about the annual rate of interest, so since this was paid over $5$ years, we divide our answer by $5$ to get approximately $11\%$ interest per year.